# How to fill a linearlayout without statically declaring a width?

Tags: android

I am trying to fill a `LinearLayout` with two elements.
Where, both views must be visible.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textandclear"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:hint="BoxMustExtend"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:paddingRight="32dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dip"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="32dip"
            android:layout_height="32dip"
            android:paddingBottom="8dip"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

It currently looks like this:

[image: Clear Button Next to Text Android]

I want the AutoCompleteView to Extend, just enough so that the Clear Button Fits in.
How can I do this?

Comment: Set your AutoCompleteTextView's width to fill_parent and add: android:layout_weight="1" to it. That should achieve the effect you're looking for. You can also remove the minWidth attribute

Comment: @Guardanis Thanks, that worked. What is `layout_weight`? Answer if you want.

Comment: Glad I could help! :) And basically, weights are a way to tell the layout how much of the available space you want to allocate to the View. By giving a weight to one child (with a width of fill_parent) and not the other, you're effectively telling it to stretch the weighted View until both it and the unweighted View fill up the available space of their parent layout. If you start adding weights to more than one View, they act in a similar way where each takes a percentage based on the sum of all the weights that were added in the layout

Answer (score 2):

Set `AutoCompleteTextView` to `layout_width` 0dp and `layout_weight` 1, and specify a set size for the `Button` (as it appears you've already done).

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textandclear"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:hint="BoxMustExtend"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:paddingRight="32dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dip"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_width="32dip"
        android:layout_height="32dip"
        android:paddingBottom="8dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textandclear"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="BoxMustExtend"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingRight="32dip"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_width="32dip"
        android:layout_height="32dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
        android:paddingBottom="8dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the layout_width and layout_height attributes of your button to wrap_content  and then adding a layout_weight of 1 to your AutoCompleteTextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:hint="BoxMustExtend"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:paddingRight="32dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/clear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="8dip"
    android:background="@drawable/background_button"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

The weight will ensure your AutoCompleteTextView takes up the remaining width of your linear layout respecting the fact your button is wrapping its content.